# WebRTC video and Audio in IOS not working with 3G /4G but works with WIFI connection

Tags: ios, webrtc, stun

[carc] CAReportingClient.mm:320:-[CAReportingClient sendMessage:category:type:reporters:]_block_invoke: The operation couldn’t be completed. No valid RTCReporting and the session was started

Comment: While we aree using valid STUN server for communication.

Comment: Have a look on this url
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40041981/android-webrtc-not-working-with-3g-4g

Comment: Thanks , but i have a ios mobile application and getting issue in Iphone appliation

Answer (score 1):

i have the same problem with using google stun:stun:stun.l.google.com:19302

i think the problem is caused by the stun/turn server.

i solve and test it successfully with applying a free turn server in http://numb.viagenie.ca/cgi-bin/numbacct

and in swift i just add the

```
RTCIceServer(urlStrings: ["turn:numb.viagenie.ca:3478"], username: "YourUserName", credential: "yourPassword")
```

into iceServers list of webrtc,

this works for me, at least prove my swift side is correct(i am iOS developer), all the rest is the turn/stun server side.

Comment: Hello, I am currently working with webrtc, after I receive the Stream I see [Add stream Remote: RTCMediaStream:
default
A = 1
V = 1] but it doesn't work for me when i show up, do you have any solution for me, thank you very much

Comment: for remote video i didnt get the video from  [Add stream Remote: RTCMediaStream:], i obtain the video as inititial the local peer like:   `let videoTrack = self.createVideoTrack()
        self.localVideoTrack = videoTrack
        self.localPeer?.add(videoTrack, streamIds: [streamId])
        
        self.remoteVideoTrack = self.localPeer?.transceivers.first { $0.mediaType == .video }?.receiver.track as? RTCVideoTrack`